# What I have in my content_main keeps showing up in my other fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When I open up my app, the first page that comes up is content_main_frame. When I fill out my content_main, what i have in my main_content keeps showing up in my other fragments. What should I do?

MainActivity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.home) {
        setTitle("home");
        Home fragment = new Home();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        getSupportFragmentManager(). beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main_frame,fragment, "fragment1");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.second_fragment) {
        setTitle("ABC");
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager(). beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main_frame,fragment, "fragment2");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.third_fragment) {
        setTitle("345");
        ThirdFragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager(). beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main_frame,fragment, "fragment3");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
```

This is in my content_main.xml layout:

`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/theotherone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:src="@drawable/picture1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:paddingBottom="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/picture2"
        android:contentDescription="picture for hjem 2"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="55dp">

    </ListView>


</FrameLayout>
```

`

Comment: please post detailed problem, i can't understand what is your problem.